# Using commas between a verb and its object

Tags: usage, commas

When another words take place between a verb and its object, should I use commas?

1- Do you understand as a British person what I tried to say?

OR

2 - Do you understand, as a British person, what I tried to say?

---

3- I will sell for 25 dollars the ring I bought 2 months ago.

OR

4- I will sell, for 25 dollars, the ring I bought 2 months ago.

I know I can place them at the first clearly but I'm curious whether I should use commas or not for this structure.

Comment: I would use commas in both examples, exactly as shown in your (2) and (4).

Comment: Thank you very much